# Opportunity.IsPrivate via Apex but not Developer Console?

Tags: apex, exception, sobjecttype

I'm trying to query all of my Opportunity fields at runtime by using Schema.SObjectType.Opportunity.fields.  This seems straightforward, but I am seeing some strange behavior when I put some of my logic in a utility class.  I am running the following code in anonymous Apex:

```
for (Schema.SObjectField field : CRM_Opportunity_Util.get_fields().values()) {
    try {
        System.debug(field.getDescribe());
    } catch (System.SObjectException e) {
        System.debug('Couldn\'t access getDescribe() for : '+field);
    }
}

for (Schema.SObjectField field : Schema.SObjectType.Opportunity.fields.getMap().values()) {
    try {
        System.debug(field.getDescribe());
    } catch (System.SObjectException e) {
        System.debug('Couldn\'t access getDescribe() for : '+field);
    }
}
```

I have the following in my CRM_Opportunity_Util class:

```
public static Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> get_fields() {
    return Schema.SObjectType.Opportunity.fields.getMap();
}
```

The first FOR loop uses the CRM_Opportunity_Util.get_fields() method, whereas the second loop calls Schema.SObjectType.Opportunity.fields.getMap() directly.

What's strange is that the first loop hits an exception on a field called IsPrivate, whereas the second loop doesn't even seem to encounter that field at all.  The exception which the first hits is:

```
16:19:45.6 (116981222)|EXCEPTION_THROWN|[7]|System.SObjectException: Field Opportunity.IsPrivate is inaccessible in this context
16:19:45.6 (117430518)|USER_DEBUG|[9]|DEBUG|Couldn't access getDescribe() for : INVALID FIELD: Opportunity.IsPrivate
```

Any idea what is going on?  I'm less surprised by there being issues with field accessibility than I am with getting DIFFERENT behavior between the two loops.  It seems like for all practical purposes they are both running the same code, but obviously they're not since they are behaving differently.

Comment: Check the API Version of your `Apex Class`.

Comment: API version of the class is 34.0.

Comment: I'm going to guess that the API version of the Util class is higher than the API version of the class that calls it (the one posted above). The Util class gets a field `isPrivate` known as of the Util's API version but the `getDescribe()` on that field fails in the OP class above as that is at a lower API version

Comment: I was able to reproduce, it seems like the `Metadata API` can't see this field for some reason. Can't access it in `Execute Anonymous` or through the `Query Editor`. I would recommend you open a case with Support.

Comment: Did you try checking FLS and making sure it's `Visible`?

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

Out of curiousity I opened a case, and support resolved the issue by setting FLS to visible.

> We investigated and found that :
>
> - The field IsPrivate was not visible to the user who is running, when we went and changed the FLS for the field to visible we were getting results in dev console without any errors
> - The class was running in System mode hence was not giving any error

I used the following to reproduce.

**The following class can be used to demonstrate:**

```
public class OpportunityIsPrivateBug
{
    public static final SObjectField problemField = Opportunity.IsPrivate;
    public static DescribeFieldResult getProblemFieldDescribe() { return problemField.getDescribe(); }
}
```

**In Execute Anonymous, the following outputs the first debug:**

```
try
{
    system.debug(OpportunityIsPrivateBug.getProblemFieldDescribe());
}
catch (SObjectException sox)
{
    system.debug(sox);
}
```

**While the following outputs the second debug:**

```
try
{
    system.debug(OpportunityIsPrivateBug.problemField.getDescribe());
}
catch (SObjectException sox)
{
    system.debug(sox);
}
```