# Opportunity field HasOpenActivity does not exist

Tags: opportunity, standard-objects, fields, field-level-security, standard-field

I'm experiencing an error similar to **[this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/112716/opportunity-isprivate-via-apex-but-not-developer-console)**. With the same Error message, but another field. This shows up on my packaged visual force page, which is querying `Opportunity.getDescribe().fields`

> Field Opportunity.HasOpenActivity is inaccessible in this context

But I can't use Adrians solution (FLS) since my field does not even appear on the opportunity fields list. I checked this in several orgs and couldn't find it.
This **[reference](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter16/release-notes/rn_api_objects_changed.htm)** introduces it in version 35. And according to the **[docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_opportunity.htm)** it should still be there.

Am I missing something? Do I need to enable any feature or something?